# Can this code be used to connect to a SQL server 2008?

Tags: java, android, sql

I'm trying to connect to a Microsoft SQL 2008 server, this seems to work for others, but I'm having no luck.  I know it isn't the best practice to directly  connect to the server, but this app is only for demonstration and won't be distributed beyond my device.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

import net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.*;

public void query2()
{
    Log.i("Android"," MySQL Connect Example.");
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        String driver = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
        //test = com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.class;
        String connString = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://server_ip_address               
        :1433/DBNAME;encrypt=fasle;user=xxxxxxxxx;password=xxxxxxxx;instance=SQLEXPRESS;";
        String username = "xxxxxx";
        String password = "xxxxxxxxxx";
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connString,username,password);
        Log.w("Connection","open");
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet reset = stmt.executeQuery("select * from TableName");

        //Print the data to the console
        while(reset.next()){
            Log.w("Data:",reset.getString(3));
            // Log.w("Data",reset.getString(2));
        }
        conn.close();
    } 
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.w("Error connection","" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

If not, what needs to be changed?  It crashes on the connection statement each time.  Thank You.

Edit: Here is the logcat for the event.

12-12 06:11:41.273: E/AndroidRuntime(5745): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-12 06:11:41.273: E/AndroidRuntime(5745): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
12-12 06:11:41.273: E/AndroidRuntime(5745):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3597)
12-12 06:11:41.273: E/AndroidRuntime(5745):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
12-12 06:11:41.273: E/AndroidRuntime(5745):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
12-12 06:11:41.273: E/AndroidRuntime(5745):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
12-12 06:11:41.273: E/AndroidRuntime(5745):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-12 06:11:41.273: E/AndroidRuntime(5745):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-12 06:11:41.273: E/AndroidRuntime(5745):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
12-12 06:11:41.273: E/AndroidRuntime(5745):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-12 06:11:41.273: E/AndroidRuntime(5745):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-12 06:11:41.273: E/AndroidRuntime(5745):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-12 06:11:41.273: E/AndroidRuntime(5745):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-12 06:11:41.273: E/AndroidRuntime(5745):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-12 06:11:41.273: E/AndroidRuntime(5745): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
12-12 06:11:41.273: E/AndroidRuntime(5745):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-12 06:11:41.273: E/AndroidRuntime(5745):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-12 06:11:41.273: E/AndroidRuntime(5745):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3592)
12-12 06:11:41.273: E/AndroidRuntime(5745):     ... 11 more
12-12 06:11:41.273: E/AndroidRuntime(5745): Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
12-12 06:11:41.273: E/AndroidRuntime(5745):     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:182)
12-12 06:11:41.273: E/AndroidRuntime(5745):     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:140)
12-12 06:11:41.273: E/AndroidRuntime(5745):     at com.nateapp.finalproject.MainActivity.sendData(MainActivity.java:266)
12-12 06:11:41.273: E/AndroidRuntime(5745):     ... 14 more

All it needs to be able to do is an insert statement.

Comment: What happened when you actually run the program?

Comment: It is a typo or maybe the problem? encrypt=fasle

Comment: This ought to be the answer that you accept.

Answer (score 1):

What does "crashes" look like?  Post the stack trace.

This code is wrong on every level.  You shouldn't be creating connections that way in a method that interacts with a database.  It's better to create it elsewhere (e.g. get it from a pool) and pass it into the method.

You don't close `ResultSet` or `Statement`.  Closing the `Connection` won't clean those up.  You should close them in a `finally` block.

This is the reason for your problem:

```
12-12 06:11:41.273: E/AndroidRuntime(5745): Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
```

"No suitable driver" usually means that the connection URL is borked.  Check that.